# nodeJs, Express get response and call another function

Tags: node.js, express

I have post.route.js where I mention

```
var post = require('../controllers/post.controller');
router.route('/posts').get(post.getPosts, post.setCache);
```

and my post.controller.js has the

```
exports.getPosts = function(req, res, next) {
    var qstring = postQueryString;
    getPostsDataByQuery(qstring,req,res,next);
}

function getPostsDataByQuery(queryString,req, res, next){
  logger.info('start',req.route.path);
  // some code here
  return res.json(rows);
  next();
};

exports.setCache = function(req, res, next){
    console.log('here in set function');
   cache.setExp(req, rows);
   return true;
 }
```

if in the setExp I log the not showing me

```
exports.setExp = function(req, data){
    console.log('here');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the `next` method:

```
function getPosts(queryString, req, res, next){
  // your code
  next();
};
 function setCache(req, res) {
   cache.setExp(req.originalUrl, process.env.CACHE_POST_EXP_TIME, rows);
   return true;
 }

 router.route('/posts').get(post.getPosts, post.setCache);
```

Comment: Sorry but what about the return res.json(rows);  in getPosts does it work or need to remove from getPosts

Comment: You can `res.json()` without the return and calling `next()` right after will pass to the next function `setCache` in this example. Look I've been doing it in a sandbox app: 
`
router.get('/middleware', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.originalUrl);
  res.json({ test: 'this is a middleware test' });
  next();
}, (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('this is a test', req.originalUrl);
  return true;
})
`

Comment: If still call `return` your call to `next()` won't happen, just try `res.json(rows); next();`